How to resolve configuration of a peripheral driver in C++?
I have been solving following architectural problem. I have been implementing a software driver for a fpga peripheral (basically a digital filter with two filtering algorithms). The main goals of the driver are:

configure the digital filter
make available the filtered values

Due to the fact that two algorithms are used the peripheral requires two types of configuration

in case a low pass filter is implemented at the fpga level the configuration consists of cut-off frequencies
in case an averaging filter is implemented at the fpga level the configuration consists of the averaging window length

It is worthwhile to say that in both cases the configuration will be very simple - only two bits are written in the configuration register of the peripheral
enum class FilterLowPassConfig {
  k1kHzLowPass = 0,
  k10kHzLowPass = 1,
  k20kHzLowPass = 2,
  k40kHzLowPass = 3
};

enum class FilterAverageConfig {
  kWindowSize256 = 0,
  kWindowSize128 = 1,
  kWindowSize64 = 2,
  kWindowSize32 = 3
};

But the method for accesing the filted values is exactly the same in both cases.
It seems to me that I can implement the driver as one class consuming different types of configuration in its constructor. Based on that I would implement an inheritance at the configuration level (I need to define a common configuration type in my opinion). The problem which I have is how to implement the configuration because it consists of only fixed values for a given register i.e. C++ enum is suitable for a configuration but as far as I know inheritance between enums isn't possible. May I ask you for an advice how to solve this issue?
I have been looking for a clean solution which will be readily extandable (in a situation when other filtering algorithms will be implemented at the fpga level). Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Could you clarify what the purpose of the enum is and why you want to extend it via inheritance: is it to chose between the available algorithms at construction? or is it also a parameter for the filter?

@Christophe thank you for your reaction. I have just attempted to clarify your questions via editing of my question.

Why can't those filtering algorithms be separate objects? I assume they share an API, or not? And then you would have a driver class that accepts filtering algorithms as parameter. That way each algorithm keeps its own variant of configuration, no "common" configuration (or inheritance) is needed.

@freakish thank you for your reaction. I have had the same idea but it seemed to me overcomplicated in respect to what the configuration really means.

The cleanest solution that comes to my mind is to have a base class with a method for reading the filtered values and then a range of derived classes that perform the appropriate configuration in their constructor.
For example
class FpgaFilterBase
{
protected:
  // Protected constructor to avoid having the base class instantiated by itself
  FpgaFilterBase() {}
public:
  int get_value();
};

class LowPassFilter : public FpgaFilterBase
{
public:
  LowPassFilter(double cut_off_frequency[])
  {
    // Configure the cut-off frequencies in the FPGA
  }
};

class MovingAverageFilter : public FpgaFilterBase
{
public:
  MovingAverageFilter (int averaging_window)
  {
    // Configure the averaging_window in the FPGA
  }
};

